# Dependence of decidability on the encoding of Turing machines

Tags: turing-machines, decidability

Let $f : \{0, 1\}^* \to \{0, 1\}^*$ be a computable function. Given any encoding $\left<M\right>$ of Turing machines over binary (i.e., a function from the set of Turing machines to the set of strings over $\{0, 1\}^*$), consider the following language:

$$ L_f = \{\left<M\right> \mid M \mathrm{\ accepts\ } f(\left<M\right>)\} $$

**Question:** Does there exist a function $f$ for which the decidability/recognizability of this  language depends upon the particular encoding used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claim: for *any* function $f:\{0,1\}^*\to\{0,1\}^*$ (not necessarily computable) and any admissible (see comments below) encoding, the language
$$ L_f = \{\left<M\right> \mid M \mathrm{\ accepts\ } f(\left<M\right>)\} $$
is not decidable.
Proof. Suppose, for a contradiction, that $L_f$ is decidable -- say, by a TM $M_f$. Now we construct the following TM $M'$. First, $M'$ computes its encoding $\left<M'\right>$ -- which it can, using the Recursion Theorem. Then, $M'$ runs $M_f$ with input $\left<M'\right>$, which tells it whether or not $M'$ is supposed to accept $f(\left<M'\right>)$. If the answer is YES, then $M'$ rejects every input, otherwise, $M'$ accepts every input. In any case, the behavior of $M'$ contradicts the prescription furnished by $M_f$ -- a contradiction.

Update. Of course, if $f$ is computable, then $L_f$ is in RE (i.e., is Turing-recognizable) --- trivially so.

Comment: Thanks, this is interesting. Didn't know the Recursion theorem before.

Comment: This does not work for arbitrary encodings, but only for those that satisfy the recursion theorem.

Comment: What are the conditions for an encoding to satisfy the recursion theorem?

Comment: [Admissible numberings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_numbering) of Turing machines satisfy it, but in general, you are not going to get necessary and sufficient conditions simpler than “those that satisfy the recursion theorem”.

Comment: I modified my answer, but I'd like to get to the bottom of this sometime. Sipser certainly glosses over it, defining an encoding as a mapping from an object (algorithm, TM) to a string. Everything seems to work; where is he cheating?

Comment: A minimal property you want an encoding to satisfy is that two non-equivalent objects don't get mapped to the same string.

Comment: What else can you impose, at that level of abstraction?

Comment: Well, there are all kinds of things you might impose. E.g., you can impose that various constructions on Turing machines are computable; in particular, the s-m-n theorem (given an encoding of a Turing machine and an input, you can compute an encoding of the corresponding Turing machine where that input is hard-wired). Or, you can impose that there is a universal Turing machine: i.e., $U$ such that $U(\langle M\rangle,x)\simeq M(x)$.

Comment: Ah yes—in our course we do precisely the latter. We state it as a theorem and majorly handwave the proof. I guess mischief can occur here if careless.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Can you actually prove that there is some bad encoding that makes this particular language in the question decidable? I tried for some time and cannot find a mischievous encoding that does so...

Comment: @user21820 Here is the simplest I can think of. Let $f$ be the constant $0$ function, let $\{M_{2n}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ be an enumeration of Turing machines that accept $0$, and $\{M_{2n+1}:n\in\mathbb N\}$ an enumeration of Turing machines that do not accept $0$, and put $\langle M_n\rangle=n$. Then $\{\langle M\rangle:M\text{ accepts }f(\langle M\rangle)\}=\{n:n\text{ even}\}$ is decidable.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Sorry, that was not the question I wanted to ask. I wanted to ask if there is a single encoding such that $L_f$ is decidable for every computable $f$. Even in the special case where $f$ is the identity function, I was unable to find an encoding that works.

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can do it for the identity. For *all* computable $f$ at once, that sounds unlikely.

Comment: No, wait. If $f(n)=n$, then $L_f$ is always undecidable: otherwise there is $M$ that accepts exactly the complement of $L_f$, and then $\def\<#1>{\langle#1\rangle}\<M>\in L_f\iff M \text{ accepts }\<M>\iff\<M>\notin L_f$, a contradiction. I believe the same argument can be adapted to all *injective* computable $f$. However, for most sufficiently non-injective computable $f$, one can make $L_f$ decidable (individually). For example, assume that $f(2n)=f(2n+1)$ for all $n$, and define an enumeration of TM by induction so that $M_{2n}$ is the lexicographically first as yet unenumerated TM ...

Comment: ... that accepts $f(2n)=f(2n+1)$, and $M_{2n+1}$ the first unenumerated TM that does not accept $f(2n)=f(2n+1)$. It is easy to see that all TM are eventually enumerated, and then this enumeration (with $\langle M_n\rangle=n$) makes $L_f$ the set of even numbers as above.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Thanks! No wonder I couldn't find an encoding! That was kind of surprising; it felt possible. =)

Comment: @user21820 I expanded my last two comments to an answer, giving a complete classification of $f$ such that the decidability of $L_f$ depends on the encoding.

Answer (score 5):

For a given computable $f$, the decidability of $L_f$ is independent of the encoding of Turing machines if and only $f$ is eventually injective (i.e., there exists a finite $X\subseteq\def\N{\mathbb N}\N$ such that $f\restriction(\N\smallsetminus X)$ is injective, or equivalently, $\{\def\<#1>{\langle#1\rangle}\<n,m>:n\ne m,f(n)=f(m)\}$ is finite).

1. **If $f$ is computable and eventually injective, then $L_f$ is undecidable for any encoding.**

Assume for contradiction that $L_f$ is decidable. Then
$$\{m\in\N:\exists n\in\N\:(f(n)=m\land n\notin L_f)\}$$
is r.e., hence it is accepted by infinitely many Turing machines; in particular, using the assumption, it is accepted by a TM $M$ such that $f(n)\ne f(\<M>)$ for all $n\ne\<M>$. Then
$$\<M>\in L_f\iff M\text{ accepts }f(\<M>)\iff\<M>\notin L_f,$$
a contradiction.

2. **If $f$ is not eventually injective, then the decidability of $L_f$ depends on the encoding.**

As shown in Aryeh’s answer, $L_f$ is undecidable under the standard encoding, hence it suffices to exhibit an encoding that makes $L_f$ is decidable. Let $\{M_m:m\in\N\}$ be any enumeration of TMs, and define $X\subseteq\N$ by
$$n\in X\iff|\{m<n:f(n)=f(m)\}|\text{ is even.}$$
We define a new enumeration $\{M'_n:n\in\N\}$ by
$M'_n=M_{m(n)}$, where $m(n)$ is defined by induction on $n$:
$$m(n)=\begin{cases}
  \min\bigl\{m\in\N\smallsetminus\{m(i):i<n\}:M_m\text{ accepts }f(n)\bigr\},&\text{if }n\in X,\\
  \min\bigl\{m\in\N\smallsetminus\{m(i):i<n\}:M_m\text{ does not accept }f(n)\bigr\},&\text{if }n\notin X.
\end{cases}$$
To see that $\{M'_n:n\in\N\}$ indeed enumerates all TMs, assume for contradiction that $m$ is least such that $m\ne m(n)$ for all $n\in\N$. Since $f$ is not eventually injective, there are $n<n'$ such that $f(n)=f(n')$ and $\{0,\dots,m-1\}\subseteq\{m(i):i<n\}$. We may assume $n'>n$ is smallest such that $f(n')=f(n)$, which implies
$$n\in X\iff n'\notin X.$$
Thus, either $n''=n$ or $n''=n'$ satisfies
$$M_m\text{ accepts }f(n'')\iff n''\in X,$$
which implies $m(n'')=m$ by the definition of $m(n'')$, a contradiction.

Thus, we may define an encoding of TM by $\<M'_n>=n$, and then it follows from the definition that
$$L_f=X,$$
which is decidable.

---

The answer above assumes that an encoding of TM has to be injective; this is not specified in the OP, but I suppose this is just an omission, as I fail to see how something that assigns the same code to two different TM can be considered an “encoding” of TM.

Anyway, if we allow non-injective encodings, the answer is that the decidability of $L_f$ depends on the encoding for *every* $f$: it is undecidable under the standard encoding by Aryeh’s answer, while it is trivially decidable (because finite) for the constant encoding $\<M>=0$.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the illuminating answer! =)